# How to add UIWebView in Cocoa Touch Library and use it in Application

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

I'm a newbie in `iOS` `programming`, i am trying  to make an `iOS` library that can be useful on my future applications. The app will have a button that will call the library and will load a website(the address link will come from the application).
I tried searching but none of it is working.

WebLibrary.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface WebLibrary : NSObject


- (void)showUIWebView:(NSURL*)urlToOpen
{
  /*  UIViewController *myVC = [self.navigationController.viewControllers lastObject];
    //This is your last view in the navigationController hierarchy.
    UIWebView *newWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:myVC.view.frame];
    [myVC.view addSubview:newWebView];
*/
}

@end
```

WebLibrary.m

```
#import "WebLibrary.h"

       @implementation WebLibrary
/*        -(void) showUIWebView:(NSURL*)urlToOpen
    {
     //some codes here
    }
   */     
        @end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to load an URL on your webview, you need to call the loadRequest: method to perform it, example:
`NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:_urlPath]];
[request addValue:@"YES" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Mobile-App"];
[_webView loadRequest:request];`

You can add the webview to your viewcontroller in viewDidLoad method:

```
-(void) viewDidLoad{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   //custom your view 
   _webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame: self.view.frame];
   _webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
   [self.view addSubView: _webView];
}
```

You should read about UIViewController and the methods in it to understand clearly.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. How can I create a uiwebview object first? since I only got .h and .m file?

Comment: I've updated the answer. I think you should learn more about the ViewController  and Views. Good luck :)